# Pass VirtualBox Guest connections through proxy

Tags: networking, virtualbox, proxy

The computer is inside a company and only have internet access through proxy. I want the guest inside the VirtualBox to access the internet without changing anything in the guest. The host is Windows 10 Enterprise x64.

I know it is possible, I have done it with [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/)

> Proxifier allows network applications that do not support working through proxy servers to operate through a SOCKS or HTTPS proxy and chains.

But proxifier is not free and not very cheap for me.

I would love a solution that works as proxifier works but I need it just for the VirtualBox guests, so I think there might me a more specific solution for this case, any free solution for VirtualBox guest connections go through proxy will do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure VirtualBox to connect to Internet through proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/78157/configure-virtualbox-to-connect-to-internet-through-proxy)

Comment: You mention you were able to do this using Proxifier, can you elaborate? I have the same problem, but I also have Proxifier available.

Answer (score -1):

My Guest machine is MacOS, Preproxy does good in Bridge mode, filling your host IP:Port here, then fill 127.0.0.1:Port in your Guest system proxy setting(or with SwithOmegaProxy). it does work.

I try hard to understand the communicatative mechenism between Guest and Host in VirtualBox,it might be Host proxy kits do not match virtualbox on different software layer to communicate with internet,or cross blocked one, so i found Preproxy suchlike kits matched the both layers perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it's a little difficult for a newcomer. i just want to give some clues to specialists, for my hard work. As for VirtualBox, only in Bridge mode, the IPs of Guest and Host are  similar, more chance to across the blockade. ｉnoticed SwithOmegaProxy filling with 127.0.0.1: Port, but Guest Machine don't know what that means, then i use Preproxy declare it's the Host Proxy IP adress and port. such as my Guest can access intelnet through 192.168.1.4: 7890, or(:10809); Safari have to write 127.0.0.1: Port in Guest machine's System Proxy with MacOS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).